# Cyclictest for RT patched Linux Kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, real-time

Hello I patched the Linux kernel with the RT-Patch and tested it with the Cyclinctest which monitors latencies. The Kernel isn't doing good and not better than the vanilla kernel.
https://rt.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Cyclictest

I checked the uname for RT, which looks fine.

So I checked the requirements for the cyclinctest and it states that I have to make sure that the following is configured within the kernel config:

```
CONFIG_PREEMPT_RT=y
CONFIG_WAKEUP_TIMING=y
CONFIG_LATENCY_TRACE=y
CONFIG_CRITICAL_PREEMPT_TIMING=y
CONFIG_CRITICAL_IRQSOFF_TIMING=y
```

The Problem now arising is that the config doesn't contain such entries. Maybe there are old and the they may be renamed in the new patch versions (3.8.14)?

I found options like:

```
CONFIG_PREEMPT_RT_FULL=y
CONFIG_PREEMPT=y
CONFIG_PREEMPT_RT_BASE=y
CONFIG_HIGH_RES_TIMERS=y
```

Is that enought in the 3.x kernel to provide the required from above? Anyone a hint?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's a lot that must be done to get hard realtime performance under PREEMPT_RT. Here are the things I am aware of. Entries marked with an asterisk apply to your current position.

- Patch the kernel with PREEMPT_RT (as you already did), and enable CONFIG_PREEMPT_RT_FULL (which used to be called CONFIG_PREEMPT_RT, as you correctly derived).
- Disable processor frequency scaling (either by removing it from the kernel configuration or by changing the governor or its settings). (*)

  - Reasoning: Changing a core's frequency takes a while, during which the core does no useful work. This causes high latencies.
  - To remove this, look under the ACPI options in the kernel settings.
  - If you don't want to remove this capability from the kernel, you can set the cpufreq governor to "performance" to lock it into its highest frequency.
- Disable deep CPU sleep states

  - Reasoning: Like switching frequencies, Waking the CPU from a deep sleep can take a while.
  - Cyclictest does this for you (look up /dev/cpu_dma_latency to see how to do it in your application).
  - Alternatively, you can disable the "cpuidle" infrastructure in the kernel to prevent this from ever occurring.
- Set a high priority for the realtime thread, above 50 (preferably 99) (*)

  - Reasoning: You need to place your priority above the majority of the kernel -- much of a PREEMPT_RT kernel (including IRQs) runs at a priority of 50.
  - For cyclictest, you can do this with the "-p#" option, e.g. "-p99".
- Your application's memory must be locked. (*)

  - Reasoning: If your application's memory isn't locked, then the kernel may need to re-map some of your application's address space during execution, triggering high latencies.
  - For cyclictest, this may be done with the "-m" option.
  - To do this in your own application, see [the RT_PREEMPT howto](https://rt.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/RT_PREEMPT_HOWTO).
- You must unload the nvidia, nouveau, and i915 modules if they are loaded (or not build them in the first place) (*)

  - Reasoning: These are known to cause high latencies. Hopefully you don't need them on a realtime system :P
- Your realtime task must be coded to be realtime

  - For example, you cannot do file access or dynamic memory allocation via malloc(). Many system calls are off-limits (it's hard to find which ones are acceptable, IMO).
  - cyclictest is mostly already coded for realtime operation, as are many realtime audio applications. You do need to run it with the "-n" flag, however, or it will not use a realtime-safe sleep call.

The actual execution of cyclictest should have at least the following set of parameters:

```
sudo cyclictest -p99 -m -n
```

Comment: This was written for someone writing their own application -- if you are not, then you can just skip the points that require action from the application. Any decent realtime application will do those things for you.

Comment: looks great, even If I think I almost considered all those points and some don't apply since I'm on an embedded platform. Something I noticed is that chrt -p with the pid of the cyclictest shows pr 0 and scheduling other, not sure if that is right

Comment: That's fine. cyclictest spawns threads at the realtime priority -- the main thread's priority is still 0. If you pass chrt the TID of the realtime thread (I used "ps am -o cmd,tid,pri" to identify it), it will identify it as a priority 99 thread.

Comment: using `ps am -o cmd,tid,pri`gives my two PIDs and PRs for the cyclictest `cyclictest -t1 -p 99 -n 010     -   -
-                            2478  19
-                            2479 139`

Comment: That's correct -- the priority 19 task prints to the console, the priority 139 task is the realtime loop. Note that 19 and 139 are Linux's internal priorities, which is why they are not 0 and 99.

Comment: ps am -o cmd,tid,pri,psr adds the cpu affinitiy since i was curious if cyclictest does the two task on the same cpu